# Border rendering strangely

Tags: css, rendering, border

I have a page which contains a table.

The `<tr>`'s have a `border-bottom: 1px dotted black;`, but as you can see from the image below, they are rendering quite strangely. Does anyone know why this might be?

[image]

**Relevant CSS**

```
.basket-item{
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    border-top: 1px dotted black;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.basket-item td:nth-of-type(2){ //included this as it seems to be the second td in every row
    padding: 25px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
}
```

HTML structure is a standard table, `<tr>`'s have a class of `.basket-item`

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I've saw already this rendering problem with tables. Layout without tables may work here. In general, avoid to use tables for layout. Tables are for data.

Comment: This table is being used to display tabular data. Thanks though.

Comment: It would be nice if you can provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), as it's not easy to debug on your page...Anyway, this seems like a Chrome (or maybe WebKit) issue. I don't notice the effect in Firefox. For Chrome, you can change your `h4` to `margin-bottom:1.5em`.

Comment: @Passerby Wow - I don't know why changing the bottom margin works but it does! Thanks!

Comment: @Passerby Beware though, your workaround works with zoom scale 1, but if you zoom out, the border's still messed.

Comment: @Bigood Yeah, there's always a catch with workarounds, but I think this is as good as it's gonna get..

Comment: @BillyMathews I find that Chrome has default style as `h4{margin-bottom:1.33em}`, but you have `font-size:14px`, so `1.33em` results in a funny float value; and because you have other elements (esp. `float`) under it, Chrome "calculates" the space left for placehold, and somehow ends in a funny float value too. The correct inner height of the `td` should be 200, but with default style, I see in Chrome that the height is 199.6XXXX. 14px * 1.5em results in an integer, so it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending from comment:

This problem seems to only/mainly affects Chrome (or WebKit), and after some unsuccessful trial, I finally come up with this:

add

```css
h4 {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em; /* or whatever length that ends in an integer pixel */
}
```

The reason for this, is that you have specified

```css
font-size: 14px;
```

And Chrome has an internal CSS that looks like:

```css
h4 {
    -webkit-margin-before: 1.33em; /* works like margin-top */
    -webkit-margin-after: 1.33em; /* works like margin-bottom */
}
```

That makes a floating point number pixel (`14 * 1.33 = 18.62`), and (probably with other elements below, especially `float: left` elements), Chrome seems to have the need to "calculate" the remaining space height for "placeholder", and finally ends up with a floating point number that is "very close to 200px".

**Observation**:

In my Chrome, the `<td>` should be 250px height (including `padding`). That `<td>` has `padding: 25px`, so the "inner height" should be `200px`, but with default style, in developer tool, Chrome shows that the `<td>` is actually `199.609375px` height. Overwriting the `margin-bottom` of `h4` to an integer "normalized" the inner height back to 200px.

Comment: +1! Thanks for the tip in the answer, it solved a different problem I was having whereby Chrome was clipping the bottom border of a `canvas` (dynamically resizable) I was displaying. Adding a `margin-bottom` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously the table display ; if you change your `td` or your `tr` to another display (like `inline-block`), it disappear, but your layout is broken.

It also seems to depend on the zoom level of the viewport : if you scale up, you can make the weird border disappear (both top and bottom border) : the height of `tr` and `td` switch from 250px to 251px sometimes.

With so few information, I can't deduce another parameter to change.

Without any actual solution, consider changing your display type, for either `tr`or `td`, and adapt your layout to fit you requirement.